# Changing Matching Values to a New Value Python3

Tags: python, string, list

I have a string that looks like this:

```
estr = '01010101010101010101000000000039021111083902111108'
```

I then slice the string into a list to give this output:

```
['0101010101', '0000000000', '3902111108', '3902111108', '0000000000', '0101010101']
```

I'm trying to make it so whenever my code finds a matching number in any of the substrings, it replaces the output in the list with a new value and it simultaneously creates a dictionary to store the value.

An example would be:

Output:

```
['0101010101', '0000000000', '3902111108', '3902111108', '0000000000', '0101010101']
```

Run my code and new output looks like:

```
['H001', 'H002', 'H003', 'H003', 'H002', 'H001']
```

And a dictionary is created from that output where each substring is the key and H001, H002, H003, etc. is the value.

```
dict = {'0101010101':'H001', '0000000000':'H002', '3902111108':'H003'}
```

Here is the code I'm trying I'm just not able to figure out how to write it to give me my desired output:

```
from collections import Counter as ct

estr = '01010101010101010101000000000039021111083902111108'
estr = str(int(estr)
estr = estr[1:]
estr = [estr[i:i+10] for i in range(0, len(estr), 10)]
print(estr)

ct = ct()

while estr == range(0, len(estr), 10):
    if i in estr == estr:
        ct.update()
        print('Sequence:', ct)
        ct.update({})
        print('Dict:', ct)
```

This is where I get lost. I can't figure out how to write this to give me the output I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a dictionary and use `str.rjust` to format the string values:

```
l = ['0101010101', '0000000000', '3902111108', '3902111108', 
     '0000000000', '0101010101']

d = {}
c = 1
for s in l:
    if s not in d:
        d[s] = 'H' + '{}'.format(str(c).rjust(3, '0'))
        c += 1
```

---

```
print(d)
# {'0101010101': 'H001', '0000000000': 'H002', '3902111108': 'H003'}
```

---

Note that the purpose behind using `rjust` here is to have *3 digits* for any amount of unique strings. For more than 999 strings simply change the 3 to 4 or as required.

Comment: Dude this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Single line version using list comprehensions:

```
estr = '01010101010101010101000000000039021111083902111108'

sliced = ['0101010101', '0000000000', '3902111108', '3902111108', '0000000000', '0101010101']

ref_dict = {x:f'H00{i+1}' for i, x in enumerate(sorted(set(sliced)))}

print(ref_dict)
# {'0000000000': 'H001', '0101010101': 'H002', '3902111108': 'H003'}
```

Comment: I like this way this is written out it makes this simple. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `Counter`, you just need to create a new value if the string is not recognised.

However, I'm not sure about slicing your string. Your slicing result from the code doesn't match your example, and I don't understand how you got to the example.

The below result is `['H000', 'H000', 'H001', 'H002', 'H002']` with the replacements of `{'0000000000': 'H001', '0101010101': 'H000', '3902111108': 'H002'}`, which is correct for the sliced result of `['0101010101', '0101010101', '0000000000', '3902111108', '3902111108']`. It'll work with whatever slices you give it, so you just need to fix that part.

```
estr = '101010101010101010101000000000039021111083902111108'
estr = str(int(estr))
estr = estr[1:]
estr = [estr[i:i+10] for i in range(0, len(estr), 10)]
print(estr)

counter = 0
replaced_items = {}
output = []
for item in estr:
    if item not in replaced_items:
        replaced_items[item] = 'H'+str(counter).zfill(3)
        counter += 1
    output.append(replaced_items[item])
```

Comment: The estr = '101...' the one isn't supposed to be there I accidentally typed it in. Thank  you for your answer. I'll mess around with the codes above and see which one plugs in best to my code.